# Why the select box not posting any value if user has not select the choice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

Here is I dynamic generate select box

```
if ($(this).data('trans_type') == "paypal") {
      $('#type').html('<option value="2">2</option>');
      $('#type').val('2');
} else {
      $('#type').html('<option value="1">1</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option>');
      $('#type').val('1');
}
```

The problem is , when the user hasn't click on / select the option , it hasn't post anything, even I hardcode the value. How can I fix the problem? or are there any way I can achieve:

If trans_type = "paypal" , posting val : 2 , else, let the user select the choice (if user hasn't select anything , then posting val: 1

Thanks for helping

Here is how  I post the value

```
$("#modal_form").on("submit", function() {
    $.ajax({
       url: this.action,
       type: this.method,
       data: $(this).serialize(),
       beforeSend: function() {
         $("#modal_msg").html('<div class="alert alert-info">處理中，請稍等......</div>');
       },
       success: function(data) {
         console.log(data);
         var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
         if (obj == "success") {
           $("#reply_btn").hide();
           $("#modal_msg").html('<div class="alert alert-success"><strong>成功</strong> 回覆匯價通知</div>');
           $('#myModal_d').on('hide.bs.modal', function() {
                  location.reload();
           });
         } else {
           $("#modal_msg").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</a><strong>失敗</strong> 請檢查輸入資料</div>');
         }
       },
       error: function(data) {
           console.log(data);
           $("#modal_msg").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</a><strong>失敗</strong> 無法連接伺服器，請稍後重試</div>');
       }
    });
    return false;
 });
```

Comment: Could you add a fiddle with the html?

Comment: I agree with @Brunis, a fiddle with the HTML would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the `selected` flag for the `option` elements to indicate that they are the current value?

```
if ($(this).data('trans_type') === "paypal") {
  $('#type').html('<option value="2" selected>2</option>');
} else {
  $('#type').html('<option value="1" selected>1</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option>');
}
```